# Can 'which' be used as just a conjunction, not a relative pronoun?

Tags: grammar, usage

Please, look at the bolded ***which it is*** in the following passage. I don't think it is a relative pronoun, but I can't find ***which*** used as a conjunction in a number of dictionaries. How is ***which*** used in the sentence? I'm sorry I couldn't find the source of this passage.

> Whenever our urge is to fight a specific biological change, we should
>   ask the following triplet of questions. Will our efforts have made
>   much difference a few hundred years hence? If not, this means we are
>   fighting a battle we will inevitably lose. Next, will our
>   great-grandchildren’s great-grandchildren be that bothered if the
>   state of the world has been altered, given that they will not know
>   exactly how it is today? If the answer to this second question is no,
>   this means we are fighting battles we do not need to win. If change is
>   inevitable, ***which it is***, we should then ask a third question:
>   how can we maximize the benefits that our descendants derive from the
>   natural world? In other words, how can we promote changes that might
>   be favourable to the future human condition, as well as avoid the
>   losses of species that might be important in unknown ways in future?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Jason that it is a relative word, not a conjunction. However, relative pronouns usually refer to a preceding noun (except for sentential "which").

In this case, it is at least curious that it refers to an adjective. I don't think the antecedent is "inevitable change", but just "inevitable", the relative clause being more or less equivalent to the far less idiomatic:

- If change is inevitable, **and inevitable** change is, we should then ask...

Within the relative clause, "which" is the subject complement, and "it" (standing for "change") is the subject of the clause.

Another example without a noun will show my point more clearly:

- If you are interested, **which** you surely are, don't hesitate to ask.

It is clear that "which" refers to the participle "interested".

Answer (score 1):

The phrase you have in bold is a parenthetical aside. It could be removed without changing the essential meaning of the sentence.

In other words, *which* is certainly not a conjunction—because it's not being used to join anything together. Syntactically speaking, it's part of a phrase that's simply *extra* information—or nonessential.

In this case, *which* remains a pronoun (referring back to inevitable change), and it remains part of a relative clause—even though the phrase it's part of is nonrestrictive. In short, it is still a relative pronoun.

---

From ["Editing Tip: Parenthetical Elements"](https://www.aje.com/arc/editing-tip-parenthetical-elements/):

> A *parenthetical element* is information that is nonessential to the meaning of a sentence, such as an example, a clarification, or an aside. This type of sentence component may include the following types of clauses and phrases, as long as the information is nonrestrictive:
>
> - *Relative clauses*, which commonly begin with *which*, *who/whom/whose*, *where*, or *when*
> - *Appositives*, or nouns or phrases that rename preceding nouns or phrases
> - *Participial phrases*, or verb-based phrases that describe preceding nouns
> - *Prepositional phrases*, or preposition-based phrases that often describe preceding nouns
> - *Phrases* beginning with such as, including, e.g., or i.e.
>
> The supplementary information provided by a parenthetical element is typically enclosed by two *commas*, *parentheses*, or *dashes*, separating the nonessential material from the rest of the text. Although these punctuation marks have a common purpose, the content of their associated text and their level of emphasis of this text may vary.